# Displaying loop horizontally in jlabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

```
while (minValue <= maxValue){
        valueOutput.setText(""+minValue);
        minValue++;
```

This is the while loop that I'm using to display the numbers from an entered minimum and maximum number, but I am having trouble displaying the numbers properly in the jLabel

The numbers are formatted vertically and only shows the last number in the jLabel

Comment: What kind of trouble are you having? Does it display the numbers but there is a problem visually or is the output simply incorrect? Can you provide more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setText() replaces the existing text.

What you want to do is create a String in your loop and when the loop finishes you set the text in the label with the text in the String. You can use the `StringJoiner` class for this:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");

while (minValue <= maxValue)
{
    sj.add( "" + minValue);
    minValue++;
}

valueOutput.setText( sj.toString() );
```

Comment: This made it print perfectly, I totally forgot that the numbers were being set to the label then changed every time

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StringJoiner joiner=new StringJoiner();

while (minValue <= maxValue){
   joiner.add(String.valueOf(minValue++);
}
valueOutput.setText(joiner.toString());
```

This will create string of numbers separated by default separator (,) **and then** it will pe placed inside label (assuming thats what `valueOutput` is )

You can replace `StringJoiner` with `StringBuilder` if you are not using Java8